# Conversion-service class in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, birt

I have a class called `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean` which is configured inside webmvc-config.xml as conversion-service:

*ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean*

```
@RooConversionService
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void installFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.installFormatters(registry);
        // Register application converters and formatters
    }

}
```

*part of `webmvc-config.xml`*

```
<mvc:annotation-driven  conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/> 
<bean class="com.palak.uauth.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService"/>
```

I have Eclipse Birt integrated with my application which forces me to remove that `<mvc annotaion-driven />` line.

So what do i do to register my conversion-service by any other way,so that, i dont have that mvc annotaion tag anymore?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest solving the root cause, i.e. BIRT fighting with your XML namespaces. Either check what the exact namespace error is and address that, or alternatively, configure Spring MVC using an `@Configuration` class with an `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.

You can easily mix XML and Java configuration, you simply need to component scan your `@Configuration` class in your XML files.

Answer (score 1):

Its working..This is what i did..

made new class called `MyMvcConvertor`

```
MyMvcConvertor.java

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.palak.uauth.web"})
public class MyMvcConvertor extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        FormattingConversionService conversionService = new ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean().getObject();
        addFormatters(conversionService);
        return conversionService;
    }

}
```

define new bean def inside webmvc-config.xml

```
<bean class="com.palak.uauth.web.MyMvcConvertor" id="applicationConversionService"/>
```